# Optimising SQL query - cleans up old logs in database

Tags: mysql, optimization

Ok, so we have a rather large database on a Wordpress website, we run a query every month or so that removes old logs from the database and I've been using the query below to accomplish it.

I essentially look at the total rows that need removing and keep running this query until the logs are all gone.

However, with a LIMIT of 1000 the query takes around 30 seconds to complete. The posts table contains around 400,000 entries and on this occasion, around 60,000 of these need removing.

Any help is much much appreciated! I'm a novice when it comes to SQL so this query will probably hurt some peoples eyes, but please be gentle, I'm learning! :)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE LOGSTOCLEAN
SELECT
  ID
FROM
  wp_posts WTCUP
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships WTCUTR ON WTCUP.ID = WTCUTR.object_id
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy WTCUTT ON WTCUTR.term_taxonomy_id = WTCUTT.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE
  WTCUTT.term_id IN (10)
  AND WTCUP.post_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 45 DAY)
GROUP BY
  WTCUP.ID
  LIMIT 1000;

    DELETE FROM wp_posts
    WHERE wp_posts.ID IN(SELECT ID FROM LOGSTOCLEAN)
    LIMIT 1000;
```

Comment: Would you like my.cnf ( or my.ini ) configuration changes to help the process complete quicker?  If so, additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.  How many rows are added to the table on a typical day?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a rows limit, a time would allow the oldest rows to be removed, which we might hope are co-located by clustering or partitioning, or at least quickly locatable by index.  Select min date-time + some interval and delete all < that. 
 Partitioning by day means you can just clean/drop one partition at a time.  Your RDBMS may vary!  Dropping a day (partition?) every day at midnight seems sensible!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As mentioned I'm a novice when it comes to SQL, how might your suggestions look in terms of an updated query?

Comment: Date functions allow you to create  high water line date time to delete less than.  A row limit is still good to hold down the duration of table lock.  When the delete has fewer rows, you are done.  To moderate impact on online users, you can time each delete and then sleep that long so usage is <50%.  Then you can run it anytime.  I have compressed huge transaction tables in production this way.

Answer (score 0):

`PARTITIONing` is out of the question since you are purging only rows with `term_id=10`, and that test is not in `wp_posts`.

It sound like there are more than 1000 rows to remove on a typical day?  Then consider removing only, say, 300.  But do it every hour instead of every month.  A "cron" job or a MySQL "Event" could take care of running that automatically.  (If there is more than 300 in an hour, don't worry, the next invocation will take care of more.)

You have not really asked a Question.  Is what you are doing too slow?  Interferes with other activities?  Too 'manual'?  Or something else?

If it is a performance question, then please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.